# JavaScript button to disapper button

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript. I just learning now, how to create a button using javaScript and adding a function to it.

How can I create a button and Onclick of that button I must get a new button(position:specified ID) and the previous button(Button which I used now to get this button) must disapper.

Comment: Could you at least show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Combine [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener) with [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) and a touch of creativity and you should have your answer.

Comment: @Surya: There are different ways how you can do that. Please drop the ˋHTMLˋ and the ˋjavascriptˋ you already have tried...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be able to get you started even though it isnt the most elegant solution, although you will have to edit to specify position and things like that.

```js
function toggleButton(name) {
  var x = document.getElementById(name);
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
toggleButton("Button2");
```

```html
<div id="Button1">
  <button onclick="toggleButton('Button2');toggleButton('Button1')">Button 1</button>
</div>

<div id="Button2">
  <button onclick="toggleButton('Button1');toggleButton('Button2')">Button 2</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a button with Javascript using the `createElement` method.

Like so : `document.createElement('button')`.

You can store these elements in javascript variables

Like so : `var ButtonElement = document.createElement('button')`

You can insert these elements in the document's body with the `appendChild` method.

Like so : `document.body.appendChild(ButtonElement)`.

If you need to insert the button in another element, select that element and `appendChild` to it.

Similarly you can remove an element with the `remove` method or the `removeChild` method.

Like so : `ButtonElement.remove()` (unsupported on some browsers) or : `ButtonElement.parentNode.removeChild(ButtonElement)`.

You can assign an `onclick` to a button element by defining it's `onclick` method.

Like so : `ButtonElement.onclick = function(){ /* Do stuff */ }`

Within the function defined in the button's `onclick` method you can create another button, insert it into your document and define it's own `onclick` method.

Hopefully this will help you figure the way to make your desired behavior.